# MySql: Duplicate keys

Tags: mysql

I have table stucture:

```
table {
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`content_type`,
`protocol`,
`content_id`,
`hash`
}
```

I'm adding unique key

```
alter table delivery add unique (content_type, protocol, content_id, hash);
```

How can i avoid duplication of keys if run query X-times;

Example:

```
UNIQUE KEY `content_type_2` (`content_type`,`protocol`,`content_id`,`hash`),
UNIQUE KEY `content_type_3` (`content_type`,`protocol`,`content_id`,`hash`),
UNIQUE KEY `content_type_4` (`content_type`,`protocol`,`content_id`,`hash`),
UNIQUE KEY `content_type_5` (`content_type`,`protocol`,`content_id`,`hash`),
UNIQUE KEY `content_type_6` (`content_type`,`protocol`,`content_id`,`hash`),
UNIQUE KEY `content_type_7` (`content_type`,`protocol`,`content_id`,`hash`),
UNIQUE KEY `content_type_8` (`content_type`,`protocol`,`content_id`,`hash`),
UNIQUE KEY `content_type_9` (`content_type`,`protocol`,`content_id`,`hash`),
UNIQUE KEY `content_type_10` (`content_type`,`protocol`,`content_id`,`hash`),
UNIQUE KEY `content_type_11` (`content_type`,`protocol`,`content_id`,`hash`),
UNIQUE KEY `content_type_12` (`content_type`,`protocol`,`content_id`,`hash`),
```

Comment: If you didn't set name of key - you will get the result described above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a named constraint, which should fail if you attempt to create the same constraint twice:

`ALTER TABLE delivery ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint_name UNIQUE (content_type, protocol, content_id, hash);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to check whether table already contains the key you are trying to add now (unless you're using named keys), by (for example) [`SHOW INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html):

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM table1;
```